# Microsoft Graph - Accessing /me or /user/{id}/ endpoints using client_credentials flow - requested user is invalid

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api

We're using the client_credentials flow to get access for our application to tenants environments. The application has the correct scopes, and we get an access token that is working for other endpoints like `/users` but when doing a request like the following we get error messages.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUser",
        "message": "The requested user '{userId}@{tenantId}' is invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b72d26a3-d0ad-42eb-a3d3-35951cb42b3d",
            "date": "2020-01-21T10:21:28"
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that there's no "me" when we're just an application, but how do we access these types of endpoints in that case? Do I have to have a user to act as, as well? That seems to me like it defeats the purpose of a daemon like this. Cannot find any clear documentation on this matter. On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#use-a-token) in the docs on the *use a token section* they even refer to a */me* endpoint, which is incorrect in that case.

I've tried requesting the `/users/{id}/findRooms` endpoint with all different kinds of ID's I can find in the access token - none of them work.
Other people with the same issue, that have yet to resolve it.

[1. Feedback area in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findroomlists?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#feedback)

[2. Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4097)

Best regards,
Christopher

Comment: There are only two User IDs - `id` (a GUID) and `userPrincipalName` (and Email address).

Comment: Yes - this is obvious. What Im asking is why does the application ID (appid or sub in the token) or me not work to access these resources?

Comment: In Graph everything stems off the user, with a few exceptions, so there has to be a valid user in the URL. `/me` doesn't work because there is no "me" if a user is not logged in. The app ID doesn't work because it isn't a user :). Unfortunately the `/findRooms` API was attached to the user entity. However, it's replacement, the [Places API](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-beta), isn't attached to a user. This may be a simpler solution for your scenario, avoiding the necessity of looking up a user ID.

Comment: Thank you Jason, this answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Using the `/users/{user-id}` is the only pattern that will work with client credentials. In your case, this should work, so maybe it's an issue with the `id` you are using.

To make sure I'm not giving you bad information, I just tested this with an app-only token from the client credentials flow. Parsing that token over at https://jwt.ms, I see the `roles` claim like so:

```
"roles": [
    "User.Read.All"
]
```

If first did a `GET /users?$select=displayname,id`, and this user was included in the response:

```
{
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "id": "3103c7b9-cfe6-4cd3-a696-f88909b9a609"
}
```

**This is the `id` to use in your `findRooms` call.** I did `GET /users/3103c7b9-cfe6-4cd3-a696-f88909b9a609/findrooms` and got the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.emailAddress)",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Adams",
            "address": "Adams@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Baker",
            "address": "Baker@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Crystal",
            "address": "Crystal@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Hood",
            "address": "Hood@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Rainier",
            "address": "Rainier@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Conf Room Stevens",
            "address": "Stevens@M365x330971.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works for me too. My image of this in my head tho, was to be able to do it using the app access token only. So what I tested was any ID in the access token I obtained that looked like a user ID, which gave me the error above. 

Is there a reason why the app is not allowed to ask for these resources? Is it an access control thing, where certain users can only see certain rooms - or could I just as you do query the /users endpoint and grab the first user ID I find and use that to query the /findRooms endpoint?

Comment: I did this all with an app-only token. There are no user ids inside an app-only token, so you should be getting your IDs from a GET /users. Any ID in an app-only token is probably the object ID of the app's service principal, and that will not work.